# How Can I Get XSockets to Work With HTTPS and WSS?

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate, xsockets.net

My XSockets.Net code works fine when I use a "ws://" URL, but when I try to implement a secure version, I can't get it to work.

I used the following C# example code as my guide:

```
//Sample 1 - Certificate from store public class ChuckNorrisConfig :
ConfigurationSetting {
  public MyCustomConfig1() : base(new Uri("wss://my.server.ip.address:4502"))
  {
    this.CertificateLocation = StoreLocation.LocalMachine;
    this.CertificateSubjectDistinguishedName = "cn=localmachine";
  } 
}

//Sample 2 - X509Certificate2
public class MyCustomConfig2 : ConfigurationSetting {
 public ChuckNorrisConfig() : base(new Uri("wss://my.server.ip.address:4502"))
 {
   this.Certificate = new X509Certificate2("file.name", "password");//  line 369
 }
}
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR 2014/09/07-19:50:16 Could not start XSockets server.
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The system cannot
>   find the file specifed.
>
> at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32
>   hr)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._QueryCertFileType(String
>   fileName)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(String
>   fileName, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String
>   fileName, String password)    at NET.Server.MyCustomConfig2..ctor() in
>   C:\MyProjects\NET.Server\Program.cs:**line 369**    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---

It errors out on the line 369 which I've tagged with the comment.
I don't know what "file.name" is supposed to be. How do I get the "file.name" of an SSL certificate? I've been using a self-signed test certificate I made, but I don't know where to get its "file.name"
I wish there was an actual example of runnable code which I could reference, rather than having to look at generic stuff.

Does anyone have a full example of a working XSockets WSS implementation? I am using XSockets.Net version 3.0.6, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the cert installed on the machine you need you use Sample1 (sounds like this is what you are looking for).

You can find the certificate in your computer using certmanager certmgr.msc and find it by name.

Sample 1 is in case you have the actual file certificate and dont want to import it.